# C++ meta-splat function

Tags: c++, templates, boost, metaprogramming

Is there an existing function (in boost mpl or fusion) to splat meta-vector to variadic template arguments?  For example:

```
splat<vector<T1, T2, ...>, function>::type
// that would be the same as
function<T1, T2, ...>
```

My search have not found one, and I do not want to reinvent one if it already exists.

Alternatively, is there a solution for:

```
apply(f, t);
// that would be the same as
f(t[0], t[1], ...);
```

Given *f* is some template function and *t* is a fusion sequence.

edit: after some searching I found it in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/functional/invocation/functions.html

Comment: `vector` here can be any templates right?

Comment: @Ken I was thinking mpl or fusion compatible sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`unpack_args`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/unpack-args.html) and `quoteN`, where `N` is the number of template arguments your template takes. Alternatively if you implement `function` as a metafunction class, you don't need to `quoteN`. Example of a metafunction class yielding the first of two given types:

```
struct function1st {
  template<typename T1, typename T2>
  struct apply { typedef T1 type; };
};

/* create a metafunction class that takes a sequence and apply it to function1st */
typedef unpack_args<function1st> unpacker;
```

Then you can use `unpacker` as a metafunction class that takes a sequence

```
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT(( is_same< apply<unpacker, vector<int, char> >::type, int> ));
```

Or if you have it as a template, you need to quote it first

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct function1st { typedef T1 type; };

/* create a metafunction class that takes a sequence and apply it to function1st */
typedef unpack_args< quote2<function1st> > unpacker;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks. unfortunately both approaches are somewhat difficult for me to implement because number of parameters is variable and I do not control function implementation.  But there are other ways for me to solve it.  but I will keep unpack and quote in mind, they are going to be quite useful for me

Comment: I found this, looking at structure of mpl invocation, which  fixes my problem: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/functional/invocation/functions.html